# When i use curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); my secure values are modified, How can i rectify this

Tags: php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

If i have some symbols like +,/,= in $data, the values will posted correctly or not.

For ex: i have some security variables and values in data as follows.

```
$data = 'key=' . $key . '&to=' .$receip . '&messages=' . urlencode($msg) . '&sender='.urlencode($from). '&signature=' . urlencode($sign);
```

In $sign has those above mentioned symbols.

```
$sign='8sb2IRRLn1=FxQzD328WYoWILj4eamhkvY26IuLvGgGxwP6Ur+0aiZBKOOjlwNLlfKz/5';
```

after i formed $data those symbols are converted their equal values.
+ as space,/ as /

But i want to post $sign with in $data as it is. don't want to change like this.
I tried without urlencoding and as hard coded the value not worked for me.
Kindly assist.

Comment: Use `addslashes($sign)` while sending and at time to receive  `stripslashes($sign)`.

Comment: @BarneyStinson Wrong escape mechanism for wrong context. POST body content is not backslash-escaped!

Comment: Are you posting this to yourself? Or who's the receiving end? How do they expect data to be encoded exactly? Though this *shouldn't* make any difference, you can try `rawurlencode` instead, which slightly differs in how `+` is handled (again, shouldn't make a difference though).

Comment: Thanks for your time, I found the issue. the issue is while i parse the values from URL the + sign converted to space. Now i replaced then its OK.